# What's the status of the Seasoned Blog?

Tags: discussion

I've been here for only a few weeks now, and am enjoying discovering the nooks and crannies of that the community has to offer. I noticed the blog hasn't been posted in since 2012. Who owns the blog and is (was) responsible for running it?

I'm not sure what the plans are for it going forward, or if there are any, but one way to revitalize it could be to invite food bloggers to guest post and allow links to their site to help them in return. This could help draw more of a crowd to the Seasoned community if we had an active blog.

So questions are: Who owns the blog? Are there plans for it? What do you think of inviting guest bloggers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blog is going to be archived as static pages soon. As with most SE blogs, it never really took off, so they're not going to keep hosting. If we really wanted to have a blog at this point, we'd have to host it elsewhere. Given how it went last time though, I'm not terribly optimistic about enough people having enough time to keep up with it, though - we'd probably want to see a fair number of saved up posts and good plans before starting up.

Comment: Gotcha. Running a blog is definitely quite a bit of work, and people want money for real work!  Hosting on our own is probably difficult because there would be some legal issues I would guess, like who really owns it, etc. Are there other SE blogs that are still active?

Comment: I think scifi and worldbuilding have done well, probably a few more. In any case, the ones that are active are moving, and the rest are getting archived. There's absolutely no problem, legal or otherwise, with folks running/hosting their own blog, it's just a matter of actually doing it.